# Convert a string to number

Tags: batch-file

I need help regarding the following;

I have the following script :

```
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in (stores1.txt) do (

set /p stores=%%a )
```

**stores.txt** has the content like:

```
0010
0011
0012
etc.
```

The solution that I found is `set /p stores=%%a`

This output : `0010,0011,0012` must be passed as parameter to an `sql.script`:

```
sqlplus user/password@%database% @sqlscript.sql !stores! !data!
```

**stores** must be a numeric value, because in the .sql script a numeric value is interrogated

So the concluzion is that i need a numeric value not a string.How can I do this "conversion" ?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set stores=
PAUSE
for /f "delims=" %%a in (stores1.txt) do (
set /a stores=%%a
echo !stores!
)
pause
```

Answer (score 7):

Basically, @Bali C is correct. Most times, any value is a string value in `cmd` unless the context either requires or suggests it be treated differently. In an arithmetic expression, for instance, values would be automatically converted to/viewed as numbers.

However, numbers in batch scripts can be treated in more than one way. In particular, depending on which character a number starts with, it can be treated as

- a hexadecimal value (when it has the prefix of `0x`);
- an octal value (when starts with a `0`);
- a decimal value (in all other cases).

So, if you simply used e.g. `0010` in a context where a number was expected, the value would evaluate as `8`, because `0010` is a number in octal notation to `cmd` and `8` is its decimal equivalent. That's what you would get, in particular, if you simply did this:

```
set /a stores=%%a
```

You could use the following simple trick to get rid of the leading 0s (and thus avoid the value's being treated as an octal):

```
set /a "stores=1%%a %% 10000"
```

Putting the `1` at the beginning turns it into a 5-digit number, and a decimal notation number too. Finding the remainder of division by 10000 gives you back just the original number but now with the leading 0s stripped off.

*(Note: the actual modulo operator is `%`, not `%%`, but the character has to be doubled because of its special meaning beside the arithmetical context.)*

Comment: What a hack... I hate `cmd` syntax for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think cmd handles numbers differently to strings, unless you are doing arithmetic with them.

I'm not sure if it will make any difference but you can assign a variable a number using `set /a`, so try using

```
set /a stores=%%a
```

Comment: i did and when i displayed the content of stores variable with echo.!stores! it displays !stores! instead of 0010 0011 0012 , it looks like nothing is asign to stores variable.

Comment: You need to put `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the top of your script.

Comment: now the sql it takes for store values 8,9,10 inseatd of 10,11,12 from where did it takes values 8 and 9 ? there are not in the stores.txt

Comment: No idea, it must be reading it from the file though. Try just `echo %%a` instead and see if you get a different result.

Comment: yes echo %%a is ok , but echo !stores! shows values 8,9,10,10 . it looks like set /a stores=%%a it gives this values to stores variable

Comment: That's weird. Try `set stores=%%a` then `set /a stores=!stores!` then `echo !stores!` and see if it works.

Comment: hi , it was like that because of the format 0010 i put only 10 and it worked, thanks a lot for help

Comment: Ah right, you learn something new everyday :) No worries. If this answered your question you can accept it by clicking the tick next to it.

Comment: there is a small issue it displays free time the last parameter, any ideea why ?

Comment: What do you mean it displays free time?

Comment: i mean if i have 10 11 12 and i make  echo echo !stores! dispalys 10 11 12 12 12 12

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure tbh, you would have to double check the file it is reading, if that's ok then post the batch file you have now into your question and I will have a look.

Comment: @echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set stores=
PAUSE 
for /f   "delims=" %%a in (stores1.txt) do (
set /a stores=%%a
echo !stores!
 )
pause

Comment: It works fine for me. I had a `stores1.txt` file containing `10`, `11`, `12` all on separate lines, and it `echo`'d them fine. Can you post the exact contents of *your* `stores1.txt` file?

Comment: this is the content :10 11 12 164 , and look what script is tell :

Comment: Press any key to continue . . .
10
11
12
164
Missing operand.
164
Missing operand.
164
Press any key to continue . . . so you see that the last number is displayed free time

Comment: It works perfectly for me. The numbers are on separate lines aren't they?

Comment: i tested on two different computes, the same script is working  perfect  on one, and on another is repeating like i said , i don't understand why :) , is the environment matters ?

Comment: Well that makes sense if it is working on one, because it works for me! :) Me neither, what OS are they running?

Comment: one with windows 7 and one with windows server 2003, the one with windows 7 is working fine

Comment: There's your answer I think. Server 2003 probably doesn't support all the commands or the switches of the commands that Windows 7 does. They updated quite a lot of new commands and new switches between those OS's. You would have to go through it line by line to find out which one, but I'd put money on that being the issue. I'm running Win7 and it works fine as well.

Comment: This discussion is growing too long and hard to follow. However it contains good information which should be integrated into the the question or an answer. Please do that and if needed, continue the discussion in the chat!